# Rudin Definition 9.9

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations

> If  is a metric space, if $a_{11}$,..,$a_{mn}$ are real continuous functions on  and if, for each $ p\in S$, $ A_{p}$ is the linear transformation of $ℝ^{n}$ into $ℝ^{m}$ whose matrix has entries $a_{ij}(p)$, then the mapping $p$→$A_{p}$ is a continuous mapping of  into ($ℝ^{n}$,$ℝ^{m}$).

Can someone help me explain why this is the case? Rudin uses the following inequality

$$||A|| \leq \Biggl( \sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^{2} \Biggr)^{1/2} $$

I think we need to show the following, but I don't know how

$$||A(p_{1})-A(p_{2})|| \leq | \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}^{2}(p_{1})-a_{ij}^{2}(p_{2})|^{1/2}$$

Comment: Hint: Bounded transformations are Lipschitz, this implies continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it with the letter 'b' instead:

$$ \|B\| \le \left( \sum_{i,j} b_{ij}^2 \right)^{1/2}. $$

Now simply substitute $B = A(p_1) - A(p_2)$ and $b_{ij} = a_{ij}(p_1) - a_{ij}(p_2)$.